# How to optional "AND" or "OR" between conditions of where in stored procedure with parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure to return results filtered by some parameter (all parameters are optional).

Sometimes I want to get results where condition1 AND condition2 are true, and sometimes when only one of conditions is true.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ProductAndServices
WHERE
    Title       = ISNULL(@Title,Title)         @AndOR 
    CreatedBy   = ISNULL(@CreatedBy,CreatedBy)
```

Comment: You need to quantify what "sometimes" means here.  SQL Server has an `AND` and `OR` operator, but they're not the same thing, and you can't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a variable/parameter that specifies if you want to use AND or OR logic with your fields and incorporate that parameter in your WHERE-clause as well.

Something like this, for example:

```
-- Declared a variable here, but might be a stored procedure parameter as well
DECLARE @And BIT = 1 -- When 0, WHERE uses OR; when 1, WHERE uses AND

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ProductAndServices
WHERE
    (@And = 0 AND (Title = ISNULL(@Title, Title) OR  CreatedBy = ISNULL(@CreatedBy, CreatedBy))) OR
    (@And = 1 AND (Title = ISNULL(@Title, Title) AND CreatedBy = ISNULL(@CreatedBy, CreatedBy)))
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Furthermore, I would avoid using functions like `ISNULL` in the WHERE-clause, because it might prevent the query optimizer to use indexes.

So instead of this:

```
Title = ISNULL(@Title, Title)
CreatedBy = ISNULL(@CreatedBy, CreatedBy)
```

I would use:

```
(@Title IS NULL OR Title = @Title)
(@CreatedBy IS NULL OR CreatedBy = @CreatedBy)
```

With this, the query would become:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ProductAndServices
WHERE
    (@And = 0 AND ((@Title IS NULL OR Title = @Title) OR  (@CreatedBy IS NULL OR CreatedBy = @CreatedBy))) OR
    (@And = 1 AND ((@Title IS NULL OR Title = @Title) AND (@CreatedBy IS NULL OR CreatedBy = @CreatedBy)))
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

So this latter query is longer and not as readable as the former query, but it should perform better. I think. I have not tested it. You might want to benchmark it with several datasets (and check out the corresponding execution plans) to be sure.

**Edit:**

Based on a tip by [Marc Guillot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220377), I added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query. You could check out the [Query Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) documentation in Microsoft Docs for more info about it.

I also found the article [Improving query performance with OPTION (RECOMPILE), Constant Folding and avoiding Parameter Sniffing issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/) by [Robin Lester](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/RobinLester) just now. Haven't read it completely yet, but after scanning it quickly, it looks like a good read to me.

Comment: You're welcome. I do not know what your exact target is, but if the logic becomes too complex (for example when you have multiple fields specified and you want to combine different groups of fields with either ANDs or ORs), it might be better to use dynamic SQL, or use different queries altogether (using IF-blocks to determine which query to execute). Putting everything in the same WHERE clause might become too complex to maintain then.

Comment: @MarcGuillot By the way, the OP uses a stored procedure. What about specifying `WITH RECOMPILE` in the stored procedure declaration as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try building dynamic T-SQL statement in your routine. It is a little more difficult to write and debug, but it will lead to more simple T-SQL statements being execute and from there - possibility for better performance. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @Tittle VARCHAR(12)
       ,@CreatedBy VARCHAR(12)
       ,@AndOR VARCHAR(12)

SELECT @Tittle = 'Here comes the sun'
      ,@CreatedBy = 'Beatles'
      ,@AndOR = 'AND';

SELECT @Tittle = ISNULL(@Tittle, '')
      ,@CreatedBy = ISNULL(@CreatedBy, '')
      ,@AndOR = ISNULL(@AndOR, 'AND');

DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynammicTSQLStatement =N'
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ProductAndServices
WHERE ' + CASE WHEN  @Tittle = '' THEN '' ELSE 'Title = ''' + @Tittle  + '''' END
        + CASE WHEN @Tittle <> '' AND @CreatedBy <> '' THEN ' ' + @AndOR + ' CreatedBy = ''' + @CreatedBy + '''' ELSE '' END;

SELECT  @DynammicTSQLStatement

EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` condition for your case:

```
    GO

    if (@Condtion)
    Begin
    SELECT * FROM ProductAndServices
    WHERE
        Title       = ISNULL(@Title,Title) And
        CreatedBy   = ISNULL(@CreatedBy,CreatedBy)  

    End
    Else
    Begin
    SELECT * FROM ProductAndServices
    WHERE
        Title       = ISNULL(@Title,Title) OR
        CreatedBy   = ISNULL(@CreatedBy,CreatedBy)  

    End
```

I am sure you know your `sometimes` when you want to use `AND` and when to use `OR`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do it with one query, if possible

Comment: Basically what do you want to achieve by this?

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want,

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductAndServices
WHERE
    (@Title IS NULL OR Title = @Title) AND
    (@CreatedBy IS NULL OR CreatedBy = @CreatedBy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as **SQL Statement** like below

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)=N'SELECT *
                               FROM ProductAndServices
                               WHERE  Title='+ CASE WHEN  @Tittle IS NULL THEN 'Title' ELSE '''' + @Tittle  + '''' END
        + ' AND CreatedBy='+ CASE WHEN  @CreatedBy IS NULL THEN 'CreatedBy' ELSE '''' + @CreatedBy  + '''' END

PRINT @str;
```